# Calculating quarter length in pandas.period

Tags: python, pandas, zip, window, period

Sample code:

```
months = [Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr, May, Jun, Jul, Aug, Sept, Oct, Nov, Dec]
months = pd.period_range(start='2020-01', periods=12, freq='M')

for start, end in zip(months, months[11:]):

end_q = end.qyear

print(start, end, end_q)

# Output:
2020-01 2020-12 2020
```

This code returns a window with 12 months (start, end) and the last quarter of the window (end_q).

My question is, how can I measure the percentage of the end_q over the full window (start, end)?

I know how to measure the days of the first month in the window with:

```
  first_month = start.month

  # number of days in first month (e.g., Jan)
  first_month_days = start.days_in_month
```

Now I am wondering how I could measure the last three months of the window, any suggestion is welcome!
Thanks!

**EDIT**

Example outcome (note I am assuming that each month is composed by 30 days for simplicity):

- If window size is 12 months (360 days)  and the last quarter (Oct, Nov, Dec) is composed by 90 days, the outcome should be: 90 / 360 = 0.25
- If windows size is 15 months (450) and last quarter (in the window size) now will be Jan, Feb, Mar (of the next year), the outcome should be: 90 / 450 = 0.2

Comment: `measure the last three months of the window` what is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the ranges for the quarters, you could do the following to look at multiples of threes which could dynamically look at multiple years:

```
n = 3
months = pd.period_range(start='2020-01', periods=12, freq='M')    
for i in range(len(months)):
    if i%n == 0:
        print(months[i], months[i+2], months[i+2].qyear, n/len(months))

2020-01 2020-03 2020 0.25
2020-04 2020-06 2020 0.25
2020-07 2020-09 2020 0.25
2020-10 2020-12 2020 0.25
```

This method basically

To get just the fourth quarter (again this would work for a period of multiple years assuming a 12, 24, 36 months, etc. period that begins in January), you could do an `if` statement for October where the remainder of `(x+3)/12` equals `0`, so that would return 9, 21, 33, etc. which would be the indexes for `October` across multiple years:

```
n=3
months = pd.period_range(start='2020-01', periods=48, freq='M')
for i in range(len(months)):
    if i>0 and (i+n)%12 == 0:
        print(months[i], months[i+2], months[i+2].qyear, n/len(months))

2020-10 2020-12 2020 0.0625
2021-10 2021-12 2021 0.0625
2022-10 2022-12 2022 0.0625
2023-10 2023-12 2023 0.0625
```

Note I canged to `periods=48` in the above code. If you change to `periods=12`, then that would return:

```
2020-10 2020-12 2020 0.25
```

Comment: Thank you Erickson, I like your method, however I would like to keep **zip(months, months[11:])** to iterate through the datetime (because this will be needed for a second task). Also, you mentioned that this method will work only for a period of multiple years. What I really need is the ability to calculate the % of the last three months over the full window size (where the window size can vary: it can be of 12 months, but also 15, or 18, or 21, etc.. hence adding a multiple of three (months)).

Comment: Please have a look at the EDIT to have an idea of my expected output, thank you!

Comment: I have hopefully made my question more clear here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63246196/datapoints-length-calculation-over-looped-window Would appreciate if you could have a look, thank you!

Comment: @Jack_T hard to tell exactly what you are looking for, but I have updated my answer based off your comments.Not sure how you could do it with zip and why / how you need zip in later code. I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for updating your question and very appreciated your effort. I have made another version of the question, including the output achieved and the output desired. You can find it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267605/pandas-period-measuring-period-percentage

Comment: I will mark this question as completed for your effort! If you still have some time to have a look here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63267605/pandas-period-measuring-period-percentage) , kindly let me know if it is easier to understand what I am looking for. And thank you!